# CSS+HTML: tds are overlapping

Tags: html, css

On my web-site http://vfm-elita.com (it is not in English, sorry for that) - center and right columns are overlapping, please see screenshot for details:

[image: Elita TDs]

Between left and center columns you can see a "gap" with a green background - it is expected and good.

But there are no any gap between center and right columns, instead they are overlapping.

Issue exists in all known browsers

There are no special formatting applied to columns. They are usual 'TD' columns, the only CSS modifier is width that is "250px" for left and right columns, and for center - it is "auto".

Please advise how can I correct that error.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two divs with class "wrap" in the middle td element. Both divs has width: 100%. When i removed that, overlapping issue was gone.

BTW, table layout is out-of-date for more than 10 years or so.

Comment: Your answer is better. Well spotted.

Comment: I've added "width:auto" style into "wrap" class and everything works fine! Thanks a lot! P.S. I know about 'table-layout' but this is almost 10-years old web-site :)

Comment: @Budda, so *upgrade the website* to modern standards, with separation of content and design.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look and the quickest fix I found was to add a padding of 7px to the left hand side of the last table-cell in the table with class "fon".